# Steps to train and re-train a good model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training, deep-neural-networks, metric

I'm still a bit new to deep learning. What I'm still struggling, is what is the best practice in re-training a good model over time?

I've trained a deep model for my binary classification problem (fire vs non-fire) in `Keras`. I have 4K fire images and 8K non-fire images (they are video frames). I train with 0.2/0.8 validation/training split. Now I test it on some videos, and I found some false positives. I add those to my negative (non-fire) set, load the best previous model, and retrain for 100 epochs. Among those 100 models, I take the one with lowest `val_loss` value. But when I test it on the same video, while those false positives are gone, new ones are introduced! This never ends, and Idk if I'm missing something or am doing something wrong.

How should I know which of the resulting models is the best? What is the best practice in training/re-training a good model? How should I evaluate my models?

Here is my simple model architecture if it helps:

```
def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(300, 300, 3)))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

  return model

#....
if retrain_from_prior_model == False:
    model = create_model()
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
else:
    model = load_model("checkpoints/model.h5")
```

Comment: better to re-train your model with a smaller `lr` than the last one. Also, if you keep re-training your model this way several times, your model gets accustomed to that specific images which have been added recently. I think it is better to collect all images and re-train once or twice. If you happen to get images afterwards, you collect them as one again and re-train with the best model of the base dataset.